# C++ code for checking for prime numbers not working

Tags: c++, primes

I'm having trouble with this C++ code. The integer `num` is a number that I want to check if it is prime. However this program is always returning false. It's probably something simple but I can't find anything.

```
for(int i=2;i<num;i++){ //primes are allowed to be divided by 1 so we start at 2
        if(num % i == 0){ //can be divided by a number other than itself or 1 so we trip out
            return false;
        } else if(i == num){ //if we've already done checks as high as possible and not tripped out yet then report success
            return true;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`i == num` will never occur, since your loop condition is `i<num`. Try:

```
for(int i=2;i<num;i++){ //primes are allowed to be divided by 1 so we start at 2
    if(num % i == 0){ //can be divided by a number other than itself or 1 so we trip out
        return false;
    } else if(i == num-1){ //if we've already done checks as high as possible and not tripped out yet then report success
        return true;
    }
}
```

As pointed out below, the `else` condition here is redundant, and you only need to check from 2 to `sqrt(num)` - since the remaining factors have already been checked.

There are more improvements that can be made depending on how complex you want to make the problem. Most methods in reality use probabilistic algorithms.

Comment: for(i==2;i<num;i++){if(num%i==0) return false} return true;

Comment: There is no need to iterate till `num`. Iterating till `num/2` is enough.

Comment: I would even suggest `for(i==2;i*i<=num;i++){if(num%i==0) return false} return true;`.

Comment: Why the else? If you fall out the loop without returning, then it's a prime. It makes the code much easier to understand.

Comment: @Axel: Better is `for (i = 2; i <= num/i; ++i) { if (num%i == 0) return false; } return true;` as avoiding the multiplication means there's no possibility of integer overflow.

Comment: There is no need for the last check `i == num - 1`. Just put the `return true` statement outside the loop, at the end of the function.

Comment: correct max is const int maxvalue = static_cast<int>(sqrt(num));

Comment: @Anders K: Correct, but then you do 2 conversions (int -> double and back again) plus a floating point sqare root calculation. You'd have to measure if the overhead doesn't actually slow down (this also depends on the value of num).

Comment: @Axel : If `num` is so small as to make avoiding floating-point code more efficient in this context, then one would be better with a hardcoded array of some _small_ N primes to begin with.

Comment: Everyone seems to be complicating things unnecessarily with multiple returns, break, etc.  Why not just simply: `int limit = sqrt(num); int i = 3; while ( i <= limit && num % i != 0 ) i += 2; return i <= limit;`  (with an initial test for even numbers, of course).

Comment: @JamesKanze: I honestly don't think that one is less complicated. More code, more conditions, but less break/return statements - it all depends on how you measure complexity.

Comment: @Axel I don't see more code, nor more conditions.  And there are several established measures for complexity.  (There is more code if you do as I suggest: check for even first, then iterate from 3 with a step of 2.  But that's an optimization that you might want to do anyway.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: i <= limit, num % i != 0, and then again i <= limit. But I think we don't have to argue over this. I think this is just some kind of programming exercise.

Comment: Yes, I'm doing this for practise and don't need an amazingly effecient program :)

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to check every number, as a lot of them can easily be ruled out. For example, after checking that `num` is not divisible by `2`, you can skip all other even numbers. That saves you half the tests.

We also definitely know that any other factor must be less than `num/2` (or really `sqrt(num)`, but that is harder to compute). That knowledge can save us another half of the tests.

So now we have:

```
if (num % 2 == 0)
    return false;

for(int i = 3; i < num / 2; i += 2){ 
     if(num % i == 0){ //can be divided by a number other than itself or 1 so we trip out
         return false;
     }
}

// arriving here we have found no factors, so it must be a prime
return true;
```

Comment: "*(or really `sqrt(num)`, but that is harder to compute)*" But you have the code in that very sentence. ;-]

Comment: Since you ve mentioned, do computing sqrt really overweigh going from srqt -> num/2 ? Won't we get any advantage by stopping at sqrt since computing sqrt is expensive?

Comment: I'm just picking some low-hanging fruit here, cutting away 75% of the run time. Anything else we do will obviously just affect the remaining 25% - is it worth the extra effort? It depends.

Comment: @MohanKumar Unless `num` is very small, `sqrt(num)` is going to be significantly less than `num / 2`, which means a lot less times through the loop.  And on modern machines, `sqrt(num)` shouldn't be very expensive either.

Comment: When computing `num % i` some hardware, like the x86, also delivers `num / i` as a byproduct. We could use that as a continuosly shrinking upper limit.

Comment: Thanks. I actually already had ruled out all evens except two, but didn't show that bit of code.

Comment: @BoPersson (years alter...) "use that as a continuosly shrinking upper limit."  this doesn't apply here as we stop on the very first successful division without remainder (and return false).

Answer (score 1):

```
bool CheckPrime(int num) {
    bool yayornay = true;
    for(int i = 2; i < num; i++) {
         if(num % i == 0) {
             yayornay = false;
             break;
         }
    }
    return yayornay;
}
```

Comment: No `break`? Excessively inefficient.

Comment: @JeffSchweigler you missed a brackets for if. Without braces, your code will break in the first iteration. Edited to correct the same.

Comment: Are you talking about line four? I purposely left out brackets and made line five inline so it didn't need them. =)

Comment: Putting multiple statements on the same line does not group them together somehow. @Mohan is right.

Answer (score 1):

A small optimization for Will Ness's code, just calculate the sqrt of the number outside the for. The condition check executes many times and has no sense to calculate sqrt each time.

```
if( num == 2 ) return true;
if( num < 2 || num % 2 == 0 ) return false;
int sqrt = sqrt(num);

for( int i=3; i<=sqrt; i+=2 ){   
        if(num % i == 0){ 
            return false;
        } 
}
return true;
```

So far I think that this is the most efficient way!

Comment: I assumed compiler will perform that optimization. :) btw I've made an edit to the code which should make it about 30% faster I think.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the proper way to write what you meant:

```
int i=2;                     // move declaration out
for(/*int i=2*/;i<num;i++){ 
        if(num % i == 0){ 
            return false;
        } // else            // and the final test too
}
if(i == num){                
    return true;
}
```

But that's not efficient. You only have to check for `i`'s not exceeding of `sqrt(num)`. Plus, if you check `num%2`, there's no more need to check any other even numbers, so you can use an increment of 2. Or you can even count by *6*:

```
if( num == 2 || num == 3 ) return true;
if( num < 2 || num % 2 == 0 || num % 3 == 0 ) return false;
for( int i=5, j=7, lim=sqrt(num); i<=lim; i+=6, j+=6 ){   
        if( num % i == 0 || num % j == 0 ){ 
            return false;
        } 
}
return true;
```

<sub>(notice: this is more efficient than another answer here, which says it's an "optimization" of an initial version of this answer).</sub>

Answer (score 0):

```
bool isprime(int n)
{
    if(n<2) return false;
    if(n==2)return true;
    for(int i=2;i<=sqrt(n);i++)
        if(n%i==0) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Your solution is very similar to that of @ZelterAdy. However, his algorithm is even more efficient than yours. So what's your reason of posting yet another solution that doesn't provide any added value?