# Can anyone help me write this simple prime number program, i cant get it right

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ code for checking for prime numbers not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753851/c-code-for-checking-for-prime-numbers-not-working)

The Instructions are:
A prime number is a number which is only evenly divisible by 1 and itself.  For this assignment you will find which numbers from 1 to n (where n is a user-specified number) are prime.
Ask the user for a number, n, greater than 1.
Use a loop to iterate on a variable, i, from 2 through n.  For each iteration, check all numbers from 2 through i to determine whether the number is prime.  If it is prime, print out i and the word "Prime".

This is what i have so far:

```
 #include<iostream>
 using namespace std;

 int main()
 {
   int i;
   int n;
   cout << "Enter a number greater than 1" << endl;
   cin >> n;

  bool isPrime=true;
  for(i=0; i<=n; i++)
    {
      if (n%i == 0)
        isPrime=false;
    }
  if(isPrime == true)
  cout << i << " is Prime!" << endl;

  return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Think about what happens when `i == n`, which your loop should reach in its last iteration.

Comment: This smells like a homework question.  Homework questions get the homework tag.

Comment: Run through a couple of rounds of the loop in your head. You should notice something odd very very quickly. And then again.

Comment: Better yet, run through a couple of rounds in a debugger.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore - that's the **first** failure. There are at least two more.

Comment: % is the modulo operator, which is the remainder when division is done.  Not sure I know what "mod 0" would mean as division by zero tends to be rather undefined in most number systems as I recall.  What happens if a user enters "A" for n?

Comment: You don't really need to test for divisors up until n (even though that's what the requirement asks): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811151/why-do-we-check-upto-the-square-root-of-a-prime-number-to-determine-if-it-is-pri

Comment: Refuse to do the assignment on the grounds that a criminally inefficient prime test should at least be creative.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not going to answer a suspected homework question with working code, so take this pseudocode instead:

```
main:
    get number from stdin
    loop from 2 to number:
        if number isprime:
            print number " is prime!"
        increment number
    exit

isprime:
    loop from 2 to number - 1:
        if loop counter evenly divides number
            return false
    return true
```

You'd have better luck using a function to figure out if a number is prime.  It's easier to organize your thoughts this way, and good practice for the future, where you will solve problems where organizing your thoughts will be much harder.

[Here's a function overview.](http://cpp-tutorial.cpp4u.com/structures_functions.html)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the Sieve algorithm for this. Look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) for algorithm description. Might get extra credit for using a smart solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
 bool isPrime(int number){
    bool isPrime = true;
    for(int i = 1; i <= sqrt(number); i++){
        if(number%i == 0)isPrime =  false;
   }
return isPrime;
}
```